# Use restlet with Eclipse Virgo

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, restlet, eclipse-virgo

I am trying to integrate restlet in an application using Eclipse Virgo as the application server. As Virgo is based on OSGi, I had to use the `org.restlet.osgi` libraries and the newest version (restlet 2.2.3) that doesn't rely on Java 1.7 because the latest Virgo release complains about bundles depending on Java 1.7.

I try to get restlet to use the Eclipse Virgo web server for delivering the REST APIs, but it seems like whatever I tried doesn't work. Of course, I can start the restlet own web server on a separate port than the Eclipse Virgo one, but I had no success using its web server. Is it at all possible?

**Update**

There is also Spring involved into the story, so I think this will make things even more interesting. The Spring related configuration is below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm.ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm.ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am now getting this exception:

```
[2015-03-10 18:35:55.783] ERROR start-signalling-1           org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader                     Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restletComponent' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'router' while setting bean property 'defaultTarget'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'router' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder#5700078' of type [org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder] while setting bean property 'attachments' with key [TypedStringValue: value [/data/dashboard/geppettoprojects], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder#5700078' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$301(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.normalRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$NoDependenciesWaitRefreshExecutor.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.StandardArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(StandardArtifactStateMonitor.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'router' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder#5700078' of type [org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder] while setting bean property 'attachments' with key [TypedStringValue: value [/data/dashboard/geppettoprojects], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder#5700078' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder#5700078' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:237)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy$CglibSubclassCreator.instantiate(CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy.instantiateWithMethodInjection(CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy.java:71)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:384)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Factory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.ExtendedClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Factory in KernelBundleClassLoader: [bundle=org.restlet.ext.spring_2.2.3.v20141127-1706]
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.equinox.KernelBundleClassLoader.loadClass(KernelBundleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Factory
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.equinox.KernelBundleClassLoader.loadClass(KernelBundleClassLoader.java:146)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you don't necessary need the extension `org.restlet.ext.osgi` to make work Restlet within an OSGi container. As a matter of fact, with the OSGi edition, all Restlet jars contain valid MANIFEST files (even before version 2.2).

Virgo supports Web bundles so you can embed a Restlet application in it leveraging the extension `org.restlet.ext.servlet`. You can have a look at the following link for more details: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-tutorial/blob/master/modules/org.restlet.tutorial.markdown/02_Server_Side/04_Server_Deployment/02_Servlet_Deployment.md.

Otherwise I would be interested in having more details about the errors you have when trying to use Restlet in such context.

**Edited** (Following the new elements added in the question)

You should configure the Restlet servlet for Spring. This servlet would replace the one from Spring itself (`DispatcherServlet`). The listener `ContextLoaderListener` must remain since it's used to manage the Spring application context within the Web bundle.

Here is a sample of configuration for this servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringRestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.component</param-name>
        <param-value>myComponent</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>tracker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet will look for a bean named `myComponent` in your Spring application context.

Here is a sample of configuration of Restlet within this application context:

```
<bean id="myComponent" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringComponent">
    <property name="defaultTarget" ref="router" />
</bean>

<bean name="router" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringRouter">
    <property name="attachments">
        <map>
            <entry key="/ping">
                <bean class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder">
                    <lookup-method name="create" bean="pingServerResource" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
            <entry key="/dir" value-ref="staticsDirectory" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="pingServerResource" class="test.TestServerResource"></bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I followed the tutorial, without much success. This is probably because I have to make things work with Spring as well. I updated the question, can you please take a look?

Comment: I updated my answer to describe how to configure Restlet in your context. Hope it will fix your issue!

Comment: I am getting this thing: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Factory no matter what I try. I know it's an OSGi thing, but no matter what I did to make it see the cglib dependency, I failed.

Comment: Can you provide the full exception stack to see from where it's thrown? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the question, as I was not able to put the entire stacktrace in the comment.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have the bundle `net.sf.cglib` in your osgi container? Is it correctly started?

Comment: I tried with various versions of OSGified cglib bundles: com.springsource.net.sf.cglib, org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib,... I added import package for all the packages in the bundles. I ran out of ideas.

Comment: What I would try to test: - is the cglib bundle correctly installed / started in the osgi container? - figure out which bundle import it. - check if the versions match (export and import) - try a latest version of spring

Comment: I know that if I don't import the cglib packages, it complains about the CallbackFilter class. If I import them it complains about Factory, which is in the same package as CallbackFilter. So I think the bundle is installed. I see people fixed this by upgrading to Spring 3.2, but I don't have this luxury, unfortunately.

Comment: It's perhaps a problem in the MANIFEST file of Spring. You could try to regenerate it using Bnd. It could also be a problem in Spring source code :-( Such issues are tedious to fix. What is the version of Spring you use?

Comment: I accepted your solution as I am sure it usually works, but not in my environment. Thanks a lot for your effort.